# Android: overwrite file from an existing URI in API 29

Tags: android, file, uri, outputstream, android-contentresolver

The following codes take a `String` and save the content to an existing file `Uri`.  The codes were working well in Android pre API 29.

```
public void saveFile(String text, Uri existingSourceUri)
{
    try {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    OutputStream os = cr.openOutputStream(existingSourceUri);

    os.write(text.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
       //show error message
    }
}
```

With Android API 29+, the behavior is erratic. For example, if the function is called the first time with some `text`, the file is properly saved. However, if the second time `text` is blank, the file is not saved.

Any help?

Comment: `if the second time text is blank,` ? Do you mean `text.isEmpty()`  or `text.equals("")` ?

Comment: @blackapps `text.equals("")`

Comment: And what did you expect that should have happened? First time write "this is fine". Second time write "hello". What is the result?

Comment: @blackapps `hellois fine`

Comment: Indeed. And what would you like that it was instead? And do you now understand that "" did nothing?

Comment: @blackapps Instead it should have been `hello` as was the case in API before 29. Why are the same codes not working as expected now?

Comment: That i do not know. But try to truncate your writing with: `cr.openOutputStream(existingSourceUri, "wt");` Please report if this works for all versions.

Comment: @blackapps Yes it works on API 29+ as well as older ones! Please write is as answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cr.openOutputStream(existingSourceUri, "wt");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "t" stands for. I read that it means "truncate" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider#openFile(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String))  but I'm not sure what that means

Comment: erase contents of file when opening.

Comment: This one giving security exception for media content document